# Feedback on my answer for $X^n + Y^n = Z^n $

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The equation $X^n + Y^n = Z^n $ , where $n \ge 3$ is a natural number, has
no solutions at all where X; Y;Z are integers.

solution: the above is a false statement

counter example:

let: n=3 ,x=0 y=0 and z=1
since $0^3 + 0^3 + 1^3=1^3$ .

Comment: Your answer is correct.

Comment: if that's the statement, then you're correct edit; i just read the sum, and thought you had simply typed out an extra zero. you're assignment of values isn't quite right.

Comment: that is my assignment question will i get full marks if i submit exactly as i have done here?

Comment: The counterexample is wrong! Right now, $LHS=0$, but $RHS=1$!

Comment: I think you will.  But the person who set the question has a funny sense of humor.

Comment: @BlackAdder oops, you are correct.

Comment: you're correct it is wrong.

Comment: $$0^3+0^3=0^3$$
$$0^3+1^3=1^3$$
$$1^3+0^3=1^3$$
are solutions. The famous [Fermat's Last Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem) states that for $n>2$ there are no solution with positive integers.

Answer (score 4):

The other answers are wrong / misleading. There are three things taking place here:

- **The assigned problem** - The statement is false and x=y=z=0, which is an integer, is a counter-example.
- **Fermat's Last Theorem** - If we only consider positive integers, then the statement becomes true, and the proof is legendarily difficult.
- **Your solution** - It's wrong, since the sum you wrote has 3 terms on the LHS whereas the statement of the problem only has two